# Problemas para centralizar un Mapa agregandolo en un modal Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

Sucede que los mapas funcionan perfectamente e incluso centrados a excepcion si los agrego dentro de un modal, en un principio, ni siquiera mostraba el mapa en el modal, pero fue solucionado agregando un inicializador que redimensionaba el mapa dentro de application.js, y a pesar que ahora lo muestra, no muestra el mapa centralizado, tal como se ve en la imagen, el marcador apenas se logra ver en la esquina superior izquierda, aclarar que esto solo sucede al agregarlo al modal, uso Foundation como Framework de estilo, agradecere mucho su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
  $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
  });
});
```

**modal**

```
<div class="reveal large" id="exampleModal1" data-reveal>
<div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 300px;'></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: { gestureHandling: 'greedy' }, internal: { id: 'map' }}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
  handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
  });
</script>

</div>
```

**homes_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @homes = Home.all
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@homes) do |home, marker|
    marker.lat home.latitude
    marker.lng home.longitude
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He logrado solucionar el problema de la siguiente forma:

Unicamente modifique application.js dejandolo asi:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).foundation();
});
```

Y dentro del modal, en donde mostrare el mapa agrege lo que antes estaba dentro de application.js dentro del script, de esta forma puedo pasar handler a la funcion junto con resize, de esta forma al ser redimensionado tambien lo centra de acuerdo a los parametros que handler le pasa:

```
<div class="large reveal" id="MapModal" data-reveal>
  <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 460px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: { gestureHandling: 'greedy' }, internal: { id: 'map' }}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    $(document).on('open.zf.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
      window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      handler.getMap().setZoom(16);
    });
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

Y con esto centraliza perfectamente el marcador =D Dejo el resultado final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]